# Can you monitor directories?

Tags: java

I am writing a simple program in java, which measure for how much time the directory was opened. I can open the directory with

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(path);
```

but the problem is, that I don't know how to detect it's closing. I was thinking something like `java.lang.Process.waitFor()` but because directories aren't executable that doesn't work. Is there any possibility at all for this to work?

Comment: What do you mean with "open"?

Comment: but that is only for changes right? I want to know when the directory is closed, not changed

Comment: Simply put, you can't. The native desktop cannot send an event to a process he has no knowledge of. A process (your program) can scan for changes on a directory, but whether it is open or closed in a GUI environment is not one of the things it can be aware of.